# time pattern in node-cronjob

Tags: node.js, cron

I am using [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron). Please help to explain to me the different between:

```
var pattern_1 = '58 * * * * *';
var pattern_2 = '*/58 * * * * *';
```

when running this function:

```
new CronJob(pattern, function() {
    console.log('lalalalala')
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first patterns will run your cronjob every 58th second: 00:00:58, 00:01:58, 00:02:58...and so on.

The slash character can be used to identify periodic values. For example `*/15  * * * * *` means, that your job will run ever 15th second: 00:00:15, 00:00:30, 00:00:45 ...and so on.

In my opinion `*/58` doesn't look very useful. This will execute every 58th second of every minute, so just use the first one.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [cron man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?crontab(5)):

> Step values can be used in    conjunction with ranges.  Following a range
>   with ''/''    specifies skips of the number's value through the
>   range.

and:

> Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, so if you want
>   to say ''every two hours'', just use ``*/2''.

So:

```
var pattern_1 = '58 * * * * *';
```

executes "at 58th seconds of every minute". The second pattern:

```
var pattern_2 = '*/58 * * * * *';
```

executes "every 58 seconds".

Answer (score 0):

The second pattern:

```
var pattern_1 = '58 * * * * *';
```

It executes at "58th seconds of every minute".

The second pattern:

```
var pattern_2 = '*/58 * * * * *';
```

Same as pattern 1 so it also executes at "58th seconds of every minute".